# java.net.url is not fetching correct URL through in XML report using JMeter

Tags: javascript, automation, jmeter

I am working in JMeter using JavaScript and I have been trying to resolve this issue for a long time but couldn't make it

I want the below tag in the Sample tag should fetch the landing page URL, not the Dashboard URL

```
<sample t="11" it="0" lt="0" ct="0" ts="1705899786872" s="true" lb=" Active Member - https://data-review.wmi360.com/Reports/Patient/LongitudinalExpense?Params=QUtleT0xMzQmcHJpZD0wJnByYWN0aWNlbmFtZT0mbnBpPSZmdmFsPSZyZXBvcnRUeXBlPTMmcmVwb3J0TmFtZT1wcmFjdGljZXNMaXN0JmRpc2Vhc2VUeXBlSWQ9" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Smoke Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="5959580" sby="0" ng="1" na="1">
  <java.net.URL>https://data-review.wmi360.com/wl/ACO/Dashboard</java.net.URL>
</sample>
```

my solution is like first it logged in to enterprise dashboard then it search the element via CSS selector and validate the text after that it clicks the element and move to next page, there it gets the page title and validate it if title matches then it will go to the following if condition where it only gets the URL and display info in log I just want this landing page URL should come in java.Net.URL tag in XML report of this sampler. Currently, it is fetching Enterprise Dashboard's URL instead of landing page URL
here is my code in jmeter sampler

```
 var currentURL = WDS.browser.getCurrentUrl();
            WDS.log.info("Current URL " + currentURL);
            WDS.vars.put("currentURL", currentURL);
            WDS.sampleResult.setSampleLabel(" Active Member - " + currentURL);
            WDS.sampleResult.setResponseData("Active Member Page - " + currentURL, "UTF-8");
            WDS.log.info("Active Member Page load correctly.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `currentURL` to be reported in the .jtl results file you need to explicitly set it.

You can do it by adding a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the WebDriver Sampler and using the following code in the "Script" area:

```
prev.setURL(new URL(vars.get('currentURL')))
```

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article to learn more about what do these `prev` and `vars` guys mean.

With regards to using JavaScript I would recommend reconsidering the approach because [Nashorn engine was removed from JDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you won't be able to use this language when you upgrade to newer JDK version.